# Convert string to decimal, keeping fractions

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I am trying to convert `1200.00` to `decimal`, but `Decimal.Parse()` removes `.00`. I've tried some different methods, but it always removes `.00`, except when I supply a fraction different than 0.

```
string value = "1200.00";
```

#### Method 1

```
 var convertDecimal = Decimal.Parse(value ,  NumberStyles.AllowThousands
       | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);
```

#### Method 2

```
 var convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
```

#### Method 3

```
var convertDecimal = Decimal.Parse(value,
       NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How can I convert a `string` containing `1200.00` to a `decimal` containing `1200.00`?

Comment: I think the zeros are implicit. The ".00" part exists in the decimal even if you don't see them. For formatting purposes you should show them but instead you don't have to worry.

Comment: @nmiranda: No, `decimal` maintains the appropriate scale. `decimal.Parse("1200.000")` and `decimal.Parse("1200.00")` will return distinct values, preserving the number of trailing 0s.

Comment: I agree with @NelsonMiranda. In fact decimal.Parse("1200.000").Equals(decimal.Parse("1200.00")) returns true, so I don't see the point for this question....

Comment: I can confirm this is a problem for non-US-like localization. I my pc is set with italian locale and decimal.Parse("1200.00") returns 120000, while decimal.Parse("1200,00") returns 1200.00

Answer (score 106):

Hmm... I can't reproduce this:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        decimal d = decimal.Parse("1200.00");
        Console.WriteLine(d); // Prints 1200.00
    }
}
```

Are you sure it's not some other part of your code normalizing the decimal value later?

Just in case it's cultural issues, try this version which shouldn't depend on your locale at all:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        decimal d = decimal.Parse("1200.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup and :
decimal d = decimal.Parse("1200.000");
Console.WriteLine(d); // Prints 1200.000 
so its not a cultural thing.

Comment: Vote up, for clarification comments below

Comment: Try to change the '.' decimal separator to ','. If the result is different, it is a cultural thing.

Answer (score 16):

Hello i was have the same issue, but it is easly, just do this:

`string cadena="96.23";`

`decimal NoDecimal=decimal.parse(cadena.replace(".",","))`

I think this is beacuse the notation that accept C# on decimal numbers are with a ","

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to be dependent on the machine settings.

Comment: I know this is super old but using a comma instead of a period is more than likely a localization. Some countries use a period and some use a comma for the "decimal point."

Answer (score 13):

I think your problem is when displaying the decimal, not the contents of it.

If you try

```
string value = "1200.00";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s);
string s = d.ToString();
```

`s` will contain the string `"1200"`.

However if you change your code to this

```
string value = "1200.00";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s);
string s = d.ToString("0.00");
```

`s` will contain the string `"1200.00"` as you want it to do.

**EDIT**

Seems I'm braindead early in the morning today. I added the `Parse` statements now. However even my first code will output "1200.00", even if I expected it to output "1200". Seems like I'm learning something each day, and in this case obviously something that is quite basic.

So disregard this a an proper answer. We will probably need more code to identify your problem in this case.

Comment: @Øyvind - The `decimal` internal representation stores the decimal place zeros even though mathematically they are irrelevant. So while `decimal.Parse("1200.00") == decimal.Parse("1200")` the `.ToString()` values are "1200.00" & "1200" respectively. The OP doesn't need to specify the decimal places in the `.ToString()` method.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks for explaining :) This feels like something I really should have known long time back...

Answer (score 11):

The use of CultureInfo class worked for me, I hope to help you.

```
    string value = "1200.00";
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(value, culture);
```

Answer (score 5):

The below code prints the value as 1200.00.

```
var convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal("1200.00");
Console.WriteLine(convertDecimal);
```

Not sure what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Use this example

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB",true);

decimal currency_usd = decimal.Parse(GetRateFromCbrf("usd"),culInfo);
decimal currency_eur = decimal.Parse(GetRateFromCbrf("eur"), culInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I came up with for myself. This is ready to run as a command prompt project. You need to clean some stuff if not. Hope this helps. It accepts several input formats like: 1.234.567,89 1,234,567.89 etc

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace ConvertStringDecimal
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    // reads input number from keyboard
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    double result = 0;
                    // remove empty spaces
                    input = input.Replace(" ", "");
                    // checks if the string is empty
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) == false)
                    {
                        // check if input has , and . for thousands separator and decimal place
                        if (input.Contains(",") && input.Contains("."))
                        {
                            // find the decimal separator, might be , or .
                            int decimalpos = input.LastIndexOf(',') > input.LastIndexOf('.') ? input.LastIndexOf(',') : input.LastIndexOf('.');
                            // uses | as a temporary decimal separator
                            input = input.Substring(0, decimalpos) + "|" + input.Substring(decimalpos + 1);
                            // formats the output removing the , and . and replacing the temporary | with .
                            input = input.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("|", ".");
                        }
                        // replaces , with .
                        if (input.Contains(","))
                        {
                            input = input.Replace(',', '.');
                        }
                        // checks if the input number has thousands separator and no decimal places
                        if(input.Count(item => item == '.') > 1)
                        {
                            input = input.Replace(".", "");
                        }
                        // tries to convert input to double
                        if (double.TryParse(input, out result) == true)
                        {
                            result = Double.Parse(input, NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        }
                    }
                    // outputs the result
                    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code remove spaces/letters and checks culture. No matter decimal separator `.` or `,` converts to decimal and returns value.

```
public decimal convertToDecimal(String str)
{
    // Decimal separator is ",".
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
    // Decimal sepereator is ".".
    CultureInfo culture1 = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    // You can remove letters here by adding regex expression.
    str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+|[a-z|A-Z]", "");
    decimal result = 0;
    var success = decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
        NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, culture, out result);
    // No need NumberStyles.AllowThousands or
    // NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint but I used:
    decimal result1 = 0;
    var success1 = decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
        NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, culture1, out result1);
    if (success && success1)
    {
        if (result > result1)
            return result1;
        else
            return result;
    }
    if (success && !success1)
        return result;
    if (!success && success1)
        return result1;
    return 0;
}
USAGE var decimal = convertToDecimal(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is the same even though the printed representation is not what you expect:

```
decimal d = (decimal )1200.00;
Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Parse("1200") == d); //True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling this method in you program:

```
static double string_double(string s)
    {
        double temp = 0;
        double dtemp = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == '.')
            {
                i++;
                while (i < s.Length)
                {
                    dtemp = (dtemp * 10) + (int)char.GetNumericValue(s[i]);
                    i++;
                    b++;
                }
                temp = temp + (dtemp * Math.Pow(10, -b));
                return temp;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = (temp * 10) + (int)char.GetNumericValue(s[i]);
            }
        }
        return -1; //if somehow failed
    }
```

Example:

```
string s = "12.3";
double d = string_double (s);        //d = 12.3
```

Answer (score 0):

decimal d = 3.00 is still 3.
I guess you want to show it some where on screen or print it on log file as 3.00.
You can do following

```
string str = d.ToString("F2");
```

or if you are using database to store the decimal then you can set pricision value in database.

Answer (score -4):

this is what you have to do.

```
decimal d = 1200.00;    
string value = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// value = "1200.00"
```

This worked for me. Thanks.