# Convert string value into decimal with proper decimal points

Tags: c#, decimal

i have value stored in string format & i want to convert into decimal.

ex:

i have `11.10` stored in string format when i try to convert into decimal it give me `11.1` instead of `11.10` .

I tried it by following way

```
string getnumber="11.10";
decimal decinum=Convert.ToDecimal(getnumber);
```

i tried this also

```
decinum.ToString ("#.##");
```

but it returns string and i want this in decimal.

what could be the solution for this?

Comment: look in to this question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264736/convert-string-to-decimal-c-sharp

Comment: what is the difference between `11.1` `11.10` `11.100000000000` ? None...someone missed some classes :)

Comment: @Reniuz - One assumes the only difference is the accuracy (number of decimal points) - this may be important information to preserve in some applications.

Comment: use `decinum.ToString("0.00");` to get `11.10`, otherwise `11.1 = 11.10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already commented `11.1` is the same value as `11.10`

```
decimal one=11.1;
decimal two=11.10;
Console.WriteLine(one == two);
```

Will output `true`

The `#` formatter in the to string method means an optional digit and will supress if it is zero (and it is valid to suppress - the `0` in `4.05` wouldn't be suppressed). Try

```
decinum.ToString("0.00");
```

And you will see the string value of `11.10`

Ideally you actually want to use something like

```
string input="11.10";
decimal result;

if (decimal.TryParse(input,out result)) {
   Console.WriteLine(result == 11.10);
} else {
  // The string wasn't a decimal so do something like throw an error.
}
```

At the end of the above code, result will be the decimal you want and "true" will be output to the console.

Comment: Just a small annotation for German readers: The call has to be `decinum.ToString("0.00");`, even if the localized decimal point is comma. "0,00" will not work. "0.00" will result in the string being correctly localized to "11,10".

Answer (score 2):

this will work perfectly

```
string getnumber = "11.10";
decimal decinum = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(getnumber), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `decimal` datatype stores a *value*. The value of 11.1 is identical to that of 11.10 - mathemtically, they're the exact same number, so it's behaving properly.

What you seem to want is to *display* the number as 11.10, but that's up to the code that displays it - I don't know if you're writing to log file, displaying on a web-page or any other format - but that is independent of the internal representation of the `decimal` datatype.

Answer (score 1):

there is no solution, This is expected behaviour.
`11.10` in string = `11.1` in number

you cant store zeros on the decimal part, otherwise `11.10` would be different than `11.100`, which is true if you are talking about strings but not if you are talking about numbers.

I think your problem is on a presentation level only. Why dont you explain better what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

11.10 expressed as a decimal is 11.1, just like it is 11.100000000000000000000000000000000000.

For mathematical processes, don't worry about how it displays itself.  If you are displaying the value then converting it into a string is no biggie either.  Remember that

```
decinum.ToString ("#.##");
```

is returning a string (from the 'ToString' function) and not converting the 'decinum' to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string getnumber = "11.10";
    double decinum = double.Parse(getnumber);
```