# Bitcoin Number Formatting

Tags: c#, decimal, precision, number-formatting, bitcoin

I want to avoid any precision errors when doing math on bitcoin values.

1) Is 'decimal' the best option to use for bitcoin currency in C#?

2) When converting from string to number, are there any precision errors I need to be aware of?

Thanks

Comment: From what I understand decimal is the preferred format for any high precision value

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek why not include the language? It makes Google results easier to scan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Bitcoin amounts can range from 1 Satoshi (0.00000001 BTC) to nearly
>   2,100,000,000,000,000 (21,000,000 BTC). To avoid rounding errors, you
>   must make sure your PHP implementation supports the full range of
>   Bitcoin values without losing precision. Most PHP implementations use
>   IEEE 64-bit double-precision floating point numbers with 53 bits of
>   precision, which is enough to correctly represent the full range of
>   bitcoin values.

Even-though this is related to PHP, it is still relevant. As suggested, you should use Decimal value type.

> The last block that will generate coins will be block #6,929,999 which
>   should be generated at or near the year 2140. The total number of
>   coins in circulation will then remain static at 20,999,999.9769 BTC.
>   Even if the allowed precision is expanded from the current 8 decimals,
>   the total BTC in circulation will always be slightly below 21 million
>   (assuming everything else stays the same). For example, with 16
>   decimals of precision, the end total would be 20,999,999.999999999496
>   BTC.

An example of a String being converted to Decimal and keeping precision:

```
var maxBtc = "20999999.999999999496";
var maxBtcDecimal = Decimal.Parse(maxBtc, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Converting back:

```
var maxBtcString = Convert.ToString(maxBtcDecimal);
```

Simple math:

```
var oneBtc = new decimal(1.000000000000);
var newBtcValue = maxBtcDecimal - oneBtc;
```

Comment: Using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture might save you some trouble too

Answer (score 1):

Decimal is the best option available.

Take a look at this working C# bitcoin library that uses Decimal for bitcoin values: https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib

You need to be aware that in C# Decimal is not fixed-floating so you need to configure your O/RM or your DB to keep exactly 8 decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

> Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

If you are doing mathematical operations on Bitcoin amounts, you should use Decimal.

```
Decimal.Parse()
```

should be used to convert from string to Decimal. See also this [other Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264736/convert-string-to-decimal-c-sharp)